# How to display numbers in the subtitle?

Tags: swift

I have just learn how to use swift and was wondering how to convert the detailTextLabel so it would show up as a number in the subtitle? Right now, the only thing that show up is the Pname and the subtitle is empty. Here is my code:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("pCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = products[indexPath.row].valueForKey("PName") as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = products[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Price") as? String

    return cell
```

Another question that I have is, is there a way to write the codes in this func tableview to calculate a price and let it display in the detailTextLabel? Or do I have to pass it through NSObject?

Comment: we can't answer this. Whats the type of products[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Price") ? is it an Int?

Comment: Yes it is an Int. I am pulling the values off of a site using NSURL. I wanted to pull the original price + tax and if the product is eligible, it would get a discount. If that make sense?

Comment: did the below solution work? if not, what was the error? and are you using `NSJsonSerialization`? or is `NSUserDefaults`? or what. We need some clarification

Comment: I just try the below solution and it does work. Thank you. Yes, I am using NSJsonSerialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming `products[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Price") as! Int`, you can do `cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(products[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Price") as! Int)`